# how to split a string which is having comma and colon

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a following query like this

```sql
 SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('SARAH;10,JOE;1D,KANE;1A,SDF:1a', '[^,;]+', 1, level)
   FROM dual
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('SARAH;10,JOE;1D,KANE;1A,SDF:1a',
                         '[^,;]+',
                         1,
                         level) IS NOT NULL;
```

I am trying to get o/p as `SARAH,JOE,KANE,SDF`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's only one row of data, then you can use

```sql
WITH t(str) AS
(
 SELECT 'SARAH;10,JOE;1D,KANE;1A,SDF:1a' FROM dual
), t2 AS
(
 SELECT level AS lvl, REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^,;:]+', 1, level) AS str
   FROM t
 CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(str,
                          '[^,;]+',
                          1,
                          level) IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT LISTAGG(str,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY lvl) AS result
  FROM t2  
 WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(str,'^(\d)')
```

in order to filter the extracted substrings which don't start with an integer through use of `REGEXP_LIKE()` like above

Answer (score 1):

Don't split the string and re-aggregate. Just replace the string from each `;` or `:` until the next `,` or then end-of-the-string:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         'SARAH;10,JOE;1D,KANE;1A,SDF:1a',
         '[;:].*?(,|$)',
         '\1'
       ) AS replaced_value
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> | REPLACED_VALUE |
> | --- |
> | SARAH,JOE,KANE,SDF |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=20e5d25ad4c1b6fc79a91192b76065c8)*

---

#### Update

If your delimiter can be any one of the `;:,` characters until the next `;:,` character or the end-of-the-string then:

```sql
SELECT value,
       RTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(value, '[;:,].*?([;:,]|$)', ','), ',')
         AS replaced_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'SARAH;10,JOE;1D,KANE;1A,SDF:1a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SARAH,10;JOE,1D;KANE,1A;SDF:1a' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | REPLACED_VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | SARAH;10,JOE;1D,KANE;1A,SDF:1a | SARAH,JOE,KANE,SDF |
> | SARAH,10;JOE,1D;KANE,1A;SDF:1a | SARAH,JOE,KANE,SDF |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a3269b66b4b7dd7f8209815827141db5)*

Comment: I replace like this 'SARAH,10;JOE,1D;KANE,1A;SDF:1a', but not working

Comment: @aniltc Updated. It helps if you fully specify the problem constraints at the start rather than giving us one example to work with and then coming back later and saying it "does not work" for a different example that you have not previously described and we could not have known about.